# Create CacheManager bean with config file outside classpath

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

Currently in my xml config cacheManager is creating in next way:

```
<bean id="cacheManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache-config.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager"
      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

But now I need to use `cache-config` file from tomcat directory and the only way I was able to handle this is to use java config in a next way:

```
@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerFactory() {
    EhCacheManagerFactoryBean result = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    result.setCacheManagerName("cacheManager");
    result.setShared(true);
    result.setConfigLocation(
            new UrlResource(
                    SlsConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResource("EHCacheConfig/ehcache_config.xml")
            )
    );
    return result;
}

@Bean
public EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager() {
    EhCacheCacheManager result =  new EhCacheCacheManager();
    result.setCacheManager(cacheManagerFactory().getObject());
    return result;
}
```

Is there any possibility to archive the same result with xml config?

Comment: Have you tried `<property name="configLocation" value="file:full_path_to_file"/>`?

Comment: the problem is that path to file is dynamic and I don't know full path